# JQuery - Disable form unless value isn't NULL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Not too familiar with JQuery, but I'm basically trying to do the same thing that asked here:

[Inputs disabled until previous input filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952113/jquery-inputs-disabled-until-previous-input-filled-in)

.. And that question was answered successfully, with this being the most suitable answer: http://jsfiddle.net/WYhNm/ (The code I'm using as well)

...In my case, however, there's an exception: If the field already has a value, and if that value is not null, then it shouldn't be disabled. The reason for this is because I'm working with a PHP/HTML5 form that allows **previewing** before submission - So the field's value is passed through the form, and put back into the the field as it's value all on the same page.

Example:

```
//PHP
    $tag1 = $_POST["Tag1"];
    $tag2 = $_POST["Tag2"];
    $tag3 = $_POST["Tag3"];
$output ='<form method="post" name="post_form" 
action="process_post.php">
     <input type="text" class="tag" name="Tag1" value="' . $tag1 . '">
     <input type="text" class="tag" name="Tag2" value="' . $tag2 . '" disabled>
     <input type="text" class="tag" name="Tag3" value="' . $tag3 . '" disabled>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" value="publish_post">Publish Post</button>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" value="preview_post">Preview Post</button>
     </form>';
```

I've tried running comparisons in jQuery using my PHP knowledge - That didn't go so well as I have no idea what I'm really doing:

```
    var next_step = $(this).next('.tag');
var input = $(this).val('.tag');

if ($(this).val()) {
    next_step.attr('disabled', false);
}

elseif ( input == "" ) { //Is elseif even valid here?
    next_step.attr('disabled', true);
}
```

tl;dr - Using [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYhNm/), how can I enable the "disabled" fields if their `value` = anything non-null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

```
$('.step').change(function() {
    var next_step = $(this).next('.step');
    // If the element *has* a value
    if ($(this).val()) {
        next_step.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    // If the element doesn't have a value
    else {
        if(!next_step.val()) next_step.attr('disabled', true); // <--
    }
});
```

Only disable if your element's value evaluates to false.

```
if(!next_step.val()) next_step.attr('disabled', true); // <--
```

Hope this helps!