# disable other input[file] untill the first ( file #1 ) one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple inputs for file upload and i'm trying by jquery to disable the rest until the first ( file #1 ) one is selected then enable the rest

My code :

```html
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image2" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image3" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image4" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image5" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image6" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image7" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image8" />
```

Comment: can you add what you have tried?

Comment: actually i didn't try much as i don't know much about javascript & jquery .. i just tried some other threads about disabling input until radio box checked etc

Comment: Show us what you tried. FYI id's should be unique.

Comment: @belal See [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before posting a Question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inputs disabled until previous input filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952113/inputs-disabled-until-previous-input-filled-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable rest of fields, enable on change:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.checkupload').change(function () {
    if ($(this).next().length) {
      $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image2" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image3" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image4" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image5" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image6" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image7" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="file" class="checkupload" name="image8" disabled="disabled"/>
```

---

To enable all of them at once, unwrap code from `IF` and remove `.next()`

Comment: When the first is changed _**all**_ of the others should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

Disable by default all inputs but not the first one.
Add classes to your input files in order to distinguish disabled style.
Change style as you wish.
Add

```
 <input type="file" onchange="fileSelected(this)" id="checkupload1" class="file-design" name="image" />
 <input type="file" id="checkupload2" class="file-design" name="image2"  disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="file" id="checkupload3" class="file-design" name="image3"  disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="file" id="checkupload4" class="file-design" name="image4"  disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="file" id="checkupload5" class="file-design" name="image5"  disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="file" id="checkupload6" class="file-design" name="image6"  disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="file" id="checkupload7" class="file-design" name="image7"  disabled="disabled"/>
 <input type="file" id="checkupload8" class="file-design" name="image8"  disabled="disabled"/>
```

And by this code, you can do what you want.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function fileSelected(sender) {

   $(".file-design").prop('disabled', false);

  }


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop("disabled", true)` to disable the `input` and check then on `change` event in jQuery like below

```js
$('input[type="file"]:not(:first)').prop("disabled", true);
$('input[type="file"]:first').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {

  } else {
    $('input[type="file"]').prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image2" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image3" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image4" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image5" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image6" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image7" />
<input type="file" id="checkupload" name="image8" />
```